# Add control in NavBarGroup of DevExpress NavBarControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, navbar

Is it possible to add custom control(s) to the group header of a navbarcontrol in devexpress 11.2 ?

I want a control that folds and can accept a custom control in it. That's why I chose NavBar Control. Now, I want to add a button (or anything in general) to the group bar of it.

The control I want to add whould be like `Show/Hide Favorites`.

[image: Example on where the control should be added]

Comment: I Hope this post may help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218188/how-can-i-get-a-checkedit-in-a-navbargroup

Good luck.